# Why total drag formula include drag at zero lift?

Tags: aerodynamics, drag, theory

Total drag  =  Do + DL

Why total drag include drag at zero lift if we are interested at drag when wing produce lift?

We cant assume that friciton and particularly pressure drag at zero lift AoA dont change when AoA increase.

Answer (score 5):

There are (at least) four kinds of drag due to pressure.

1. Induced drag.  This is the drag associated with the process of creating lift.  It directly depends on the shape and magnitude of the lift distribution in the wake.  It is strongly a function of lift.
2. Form drag.  This is a pressure drag term associated with the thickness of the boundary layer on a body that is not a flat plate.  Although this is a pressure drag, it is a result of viscous processes and the boundary layer.  It is a weak function of lift (or angle of attack).
3. Separation drag.  This is a pressure drag associated with flow separating from a body.  Inviscid flow would stay attached, so this is also a viscous phenomena.  If the separation changes with lift, then this is a function of lift.  Separation around a protuberance (say an antennae, fastener, gap, etc) will likely not vary much with lift or alpha.  Separation due to stall is of course a strong function of lift or alpha.
4. Wave drag.  This is pressure drag associated with the presence of shock waves in high speed flow.  This will typically be broken into a wave drag due to volume and a wave drag due to lift.  The lift term is obviously a function of lift.

There are others, but they also start to become blurred...

5. Transonic drag rise.  This is mostly a result of shocks on/around the aircraft causing separation.  When you accelerate through the transonic region to pure supersonic flow, the shocks move off the body, the separation goes away, and you're back down to just the wave drag.
6. Trim drag, cooling drag, interference drag, etc.  These are generally made up of the earlier causes of drag, but are book-kept separately because it is useful in an engineering sense.

The only drag that is not a pressure drag is skin friction drag.  If you think about a small element of an aircraft's skin, it can experience a pressure force (normal to the skin), or a shear force (parallel to the skin).  The only source of a shear force is skin friction.  Everything else is a pressure force.

Often, for 2D airfoil data, the skin friction and form drag terms are summed together and are called 'profile drag'.

Low speed aircraft won't have 4,5.

Clean, well designed aircraft will work their hardest to avoid 3) as much as possible.

The only way to have zero induced drag at zero lift is for the entire lift distribution to be zero (every airfoil across the wing must have zero lift).  This is only true for a wing with no twist and that uses symmetric airfoils.

If a wing has camber and/or twist, the zero lift situation will be made of some parts of the wing lifting up -- and other parts lifting down.  The total lift is zero, but the lift distribution is not.  Consequently, this wing will have non-zero induced drag at zero lift.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145713/discussion-on-answer-by-rob-mcdonald-why-total-drag-formula-include-drag-at-zero); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 5):

I'm adding this separate answer to provide evidence that induced drag can be non-zero at zero lift.

First, I performed a simple aerodynamic analysis on a simple straight wing.  This has a symmetrical airfoil and no twist.  I analyzed it at zero angle of attack.  As expected, there is zero lift, zero drag, and pretty much nothing going on...

First, the lift distribution plot.  No lift anywhere (note the axis scale).

[image: Un-twisted lift distribution]

Next, the induced drag distribution plot.  Nothing to see here.

[image: Un-twisted drag distribution]

Here is a visualization of the flowfield.  Since this is a thin-surface method, we present $\Delta C_p$ instead of $C_p$.  Note the scale -- nothing is happening, it is all just equivalently zero.

This also depicts the wake lines.  Notice that the wake is perfectly flat.

[image: Un-twisted wing pressure and wake]

Next, I analyzed the same wing, but with ten degrees of twist about the quarter chord (positive LE up).  Here is a polar plot of the induced drag.  This plot was generated by sweeping angle of attack from -10 to 10 in one degree increments.

[image: Polar for twisted wing.]

The $CDt$ label refers to the Trefftz plane analysis -- the particular technique used to calcualte the drag for this case.

Notice that the bottom of the parabola never goes to zero.  The minimum drag is about .0025 and occurs at about -5 deg angle of attack.  This is induced drag.

Next, we'll take a look at the lift distribution for this wing.

[image: Lift distribution for twisted wing at 5 degrees]

Notice that since the tips were twisted leading edge up, with the wing at -5 degrees, the tips have positive lift -- and the middle of the wing has negative lift.  The combined sum of this is close to zero.

Induced drag is caused by changes in this lift distibution.  If you have an ugly distribution of lift, you'll have a lot of induced drag.  If you have a beautiful (elliptical) lift distribution, you'll have less induced drag.

Here is the drag distribution for this wing at zero total lift.

[image: Drag distribution for twisted wing at -5 deg]

While there appears to be a section near mid-span that contributes zero drag (note, this would be a section producing zero lift), the rest of the wing contributes to the drag -- whether it is lifting or negative lifting.

Edit: There was some question about how the lift and drag distributions would vary with angle of attack.  Here are those charts.

[image: Lift distribution of twisted wing with angle of attack]

As you can see, if you go to low enough angle of attack, the entire wing is producing negative lift -- and if you go to high enough angle of attack, the entire wing is producing positive lift.

The approximately zero lift case is the blue circles 5th from the bottom.

[image: Drag distribution of twisted wing with angle of attack]

Here are the drag distribution charts for all angles of attack.  The blue circles are hard to see in this case because they're squeezed into the bottom and overlaid by many other results.

Interestingly, at high angle of attack, there are some cases wehre the center section produces a slight thrust -- this is a leading edge suction effect.

Here is the flowfield image for this solution.

[image: Flowfield for twisted wing at -5 degrees]

You can see that this is very different from the zero-twist zero-alpha zero-lift zero-drag case.  Keep the scale in mind -- the other scale was essentially zero everywhere.

Finally, I've arranged the wing so you're looking at it from about the oncoming wind (from the front).  You can see that some of the wake is pushed above the wing and some of the wake is pushed below the wing.

[image: Wake for twisted wing at zero lift]

There is clearly upwash and downwash going on -- the wake shape allows you to nearly 'see' the production of induced drag.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145751/discussion-on-answer-by-rob-mcdonald-why-total-drag-formula-include-drag-at-zero); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.