# Has resultant pressure vector backward component at 2D airfoil in viscid flow?

Tags: aerodynamics, drag, theory

When we integrate static pressure around 2D airfoil that produce  lift(viscid flow), has  resultant pressure vector backward component?

I think pressure vector will point slighlty back, so it has some drag component.

Some members here call induced drag as component of pressure vector point back, so why do we have pressure vector point back in 2D airfoil if induced drag must be zero?

Answer (score 2):

Check [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/98768/65514) for some discussion on drag breakdown. (I now realize that was your question)

There is 2D pressure drag (not induced drag) that happens on an airfoil with finite thickness.  It is called form drag.  This is a viscous phenemona associated with the thickness of the boundary layer at the trailing edge of the airfoil.

There can also be separation drag and wave drag that are also pressure drag.

Induced drag is not the only source of pressure drag.

Some models of induced drag do involve analyzing the component of the lift vector (caused by pressure) that is tilted back.  Having that as an explanation of induced drag does not mean that is the only set of pressures in the drag direction.

Comment: Do you think it would be accurate to regard this question as a duplicate of the one you linked?

Comment: @RalphJ I don't know.  Clearly the first question raised more questions in the asker's mind and so they're asking for clarification.  I think I'm going to need to spend some time and do a proper description of form drag -- that one is a doozy.

Comment: @user207141 please don't ask new questions in comments. Instead ask a follow up question. Whilst part of your comments can be seen as requests for clarification, this thread is now getting to a level where it is becoming a chat and new questions are posted. Please use our [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar) to chat, use comments only for clarifications and ask new questions when the need arises.

Comment: @RobMcDonald I really appreciate the insights you are providing and by deleting all the comments here I don't want to discourage you in any way. Just trying to keep things organised. If there was anything important lost when I removed those comments, please give me ping and I will try and help out.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with an **inviscid** flow around a 2D airfoil which is easier. In this case the pressure:

1. decreases moving from the leading edge to the point of maximum thickness and;
2. increases afterward toward the trailing edge reaching again the ambient pressure (so called "pressure recovery").

These increase and decrease in pressure perfectly compensate for each other in the horizontal direction and their resultant in this direction (drag by definition) is therefore zero. These result is called [D'Alambert paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_paradox).

Viscosity is the property of a fluid to resist against deformations. On an aerodynamic body like an airfoil, this resistance typically happens inside the boundary layer: the several layers of fluid inside the boundary layer which are moving at different speeds slow down the aerodynamic body exactly due to resistance created by the viscosity between each of those layers. The net effect is a drag force which is termed "skin friction". Note that this drag has nothing to due with the pressure but only with the viscosity of the fluid; that's why it is normally called "friction" instead of "drag".

The boundary layer is anyway responsible for the creation of drag also via pressure. Due to its thickness, which increases from the leading edge to the trailing edge, the pressure recovery of the previous point 2) does not complete till the ambient pressure since the boundary layer is now in the way: 1) and 2) do not compensate anymore rather 1) is now always bigger than 2). But since the bigger under-pressure of 1) acts on the part of the airfoil which is mainly facing forward then its effect is to create a forward facing net force, i.e. a drag: this drag is termed "profile drag".

Increasing the angle of attack, the thickness of of the boundary layer increases as well and the pressure recovery on the back part of the airfoil becomes lower and lower i.e. the profile drag higher and higher. This increase in drag is more or less proportional to the square of the angle of attack. Increasing the angle of attack even more, at a certain point the boundary layer detaches completely from the  surface of the airfoil: the pressure recovery of 2) is now completely lost.

Induced drag is a pure mathematical **3**D concept which is connected to the spanwise lift distribution on the wing. Obviously a 2D airfoil has no span and therefore the concept of induced drag is formally undefined for it.

Comment: Last paragraph makes one wonder what polar diagrams base their lift to drag ratios on, an *infinite* span?

Answer (score 0):

If the object is moving but not lifting, it still will have drag.

It seems what is done in aviation is to separate *pressure*, as in dynamic pressure, or center of pressure, into "that which opposes forward motion" and "that which is used to create lift"

> Coefficient of drag = C$_{di}$ + C$_{d0}$

This becomes the "thrust budget" of the aircraft.

Thrust can be gained from converting the potential energy of fuel or thermals (or somebody towing you) to the kinetic energy of propulsion or/and  utilizing gravity and altitude.

Thrust must equal the sum of all drags or airspeed is lost.